# Maven plugin dependencies couldn't resolve dependency from internal repo

Tags: java, maven

I am creating parent-pom. There we are defining build->plugin->dependencies.
It can fetch dependencies from maven but it couldn't fetch dependencies from our internal Maven repository. getting below error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.2:check (validate) on
> project parent-pom: Execution validate of goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.2:check failed: Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.2 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact
> org.tools:build-tool:jar:1.0 in central
> (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

It is trying to pull dependency from `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` instead of our internal Maven repository. I have configured repositories and dependencyManagement still it is trying to fetch from `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` instead of going to our internal repositories.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.global</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>archiva.global</id>
            <name>Internal Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://archiva.global.com/repository/internal</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>archiva.snapshots</id>
            <name>Internal Snapshots Repository</name>
            <url>https://archiva.global.com/repository/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>archiva.internal</id>
            <name>Internal Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://archiva.global.com/repository/internal</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>archiva.snapshots</id>
            <name>Internal Snapshots Repository</name>
            <url>https://archiva.global.com/repository/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        ...
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-tool</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
          </dependency>
         </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Is there anything I missed? Only build plugin dependencies are not resolved where as project dependencies are getting resolved from our internal repository.

Comment: What is org.tools:build-tool:jar:1.0

Comment: @SimonMartinelli It is in our internal archiva repository. `https://archiva.global.com/repository/internal`. I defined in <repositories> and <distributionManagement> section.

Comment: It is there in our internal archiva repository `org.tools:build-tool:jar:1.0 `. It is internal for our project so we cannot find this in Maven central

Comment: Can you ckeck if the plugin jar file was downloaded in the respective directory in M2? Sometimes there are only metadata files and not the jar.

Comment: Nope, it is not there...As I mentioned in the question it is not pulling it from the remote repo. It is trying to pull it from Maven central.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the default behavior of maven.

When defining `<repository> .... </repository>` make sure to override the `<id>central</id>` with your internal repository. If you don't do so, maven will still contact maven central to resolve dependencies and not work without proper proxy settings if you are behind a VPN. The below listing will fetch all your deps from your internal repository.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Internal Release Repository</name>
        <url>https://archiva.global.com/repository/internal</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>archiva.snapshots</id>
        <name>Internal Snapshots Repository</name>
        <url>https://archiva.global.com/repository/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

---

For downloading the plugins from your internal repository

```
<pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
  <id>central</id>
  <name>Central Internal Repo</name>
  <url>https://archiva.global.com/repository/internal</url>
  <layout>default</layout>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <releases>
    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
  </releases>
</pluginRepository>
```

Comment: Now we are getting the followig exception dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.tools-tool:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Comment: Use <id>central</id> for the repository as well as the plugin repository because even the maven plugins need to be downloaded.
as well as in your distribution management use central for id tag.
also, make sure to not use snapshots for testing purposes.

Comment: What do you mean by plugin repository? I have defined repositories I believe that's sufficient. Yes, I modified distribution Management to the central still the same issue.

Comment: you can also check if the repo is reachable 
https://archiva.global.com/repository/internal/org/tools/build-tool

Comment: It is reachable. As I mentioned it cannot able to resolve only dependencies we defined in build->plugins-> plugin.

Comment: With <repo> we tell maven to fetch deps from xyz location
Similarly, we need to specify the location from where the plugins need to be downloaded. In your case it is maven-antrun-plugin which without the presence of plugin repository will go to maven central.
https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Comment: Add this to your pom
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>xyz</name>
      <url>......YOUR REPO....</url>

    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

Comment: Adding plugin-repositories resolved the issue